# Why does the address of an out-of-scope variable equal zero with constexpr?

Tags: c++, gcc, constexpr

There is something that I don't understand about `constexpr` semantics. Surely, the address of `x` allocated on the stack cannot be calculated at compile time.

```cpp
constexpr auto foo()
{
    int x = 5;    
    return &x;
}

static_assert(foo() == 0);
```

Still, this code compiles (GCC 13.2 `-std=c++20`) and the address of `x` is equal to `0`, which can be seen in the `static_assert` declaration that passes.

See https://godbolt.org/z/Pjrx3cb68.

Comment: What compiler do you use? I get in GCC: `warning: address of local variable 'x' returned` and `error: static assertion failed: ???`. And Clang: `warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'x' returned` and `error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'foo() == 0': ???`.

Comment: That's quite interesting, dereferencing an address returned by the function is UB, but using the address itself (the value) should be completely fine. So, it's really weird it is able to allocate this variable at compile time

Comment: @273K just reverse the condition, the point is that the address is constexpr value

Comment: It compiles with g++ 13.2 on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PGTfseaMn).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the evaluation of a constant expression you can use variables normally just as in any other expression evaluation if their lifetime is confined to the evaluation of the constant expression. (I.e. the compiler will simulate a stack at compile-time for the evaluation of the constant expression.)

The `static_cast` requires its *whole operand*, i.e. `foo() ==  0` to be a *constant expression*.

In evaluating `foo() == 0` you are comparing the pointer value, but the pointer value is not part of the result of the constant expression, so there is no problem with a compile-time pointer escaping to a runtime context (which would not be allowed in a constant expression). So there is no problem.

However, as soon as `foo()` returns, the pointer value returned becomes an *invalid pointer value* because the storage duration of the variable `x` ends. With few exceptions any use of an invalid pointer value is implementation-defined. Comparing to `0` falls under this implementation-definedness.

Therefore whether or not `static_assert(foo() ==  0, "???");` compiles is implementation-defined. Originally I expected that compilers would usually treat `foo() == 0` as false, because if one assumes that the pointer which became an invalid pointer value retains its address, then it can't equal a null pointer value. However, it seems now unclear to me what some compiler vendors actually expect the behavior to be here. As far as I can tell they lack documentation of this implentation-defined behavior.

Comment: Cannot get my head around "compiler will simulate" thing. It means basically that constexpr value in this case is unpredictable, it may even change from compilation to compilation. Who would want such thing? why not confine the constexpr to at least strictly deterministric values.

Comment: @Boris You can't do anything that would actually inspect the concrete address of the variable in a compile-time context. The definition for constant expressions is such that this is impossible. For example conversion of pointer values to integer values is not permitted in constant expressions. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression for details. The definitions given there are such that the concrete "address at compile-time" can never affect the result of the expression.

Comment: Look at the 8th example in "constant expression" section in the link you have attached? It gives an example of constexpr auto e1 = &y - &x;  which is illegal. Now look at this examples which compiles and works. https://onlinegdb.com/HC5IrgMZP What's the difference?

Comment: @Boris The behavior of invalid pointer values is implementation-defined as I wrote. In your example both the result of `foo()` and `bar()` are invalid pointer values. As a result the standard does not specify whether `foo() -  bar()` is allowed or what the result would be. Instead the compiler should specify it and document the behavior. Practically speaking, as in my answer, normal C++ implementations should consider this subtraction undefined behavior and therefore consider `(foo() -  bar()) ==  0` to not be a constant expression, failing the `static_assert`.

Comment: @Boris That the compiler is not behaving that way in your example is probably not intended, although it would be conforming to the standard if the compiler vendor documented this behavior.

Comment: @Boris In the example on cppreference `&y` and `&x` are not invalid pointer values, because the storage duration of `x` and `y` hasn't ended yet, but the subtraction has undefined behavior because `x` and `y` are not elements of one array. Therefore the expression is not a constant expression on any C++ implementation, because core language undefined behavior is disqualified in the list of requirements for _core constant expressions_.

Comment: @user17732522: On most implementations, given `char *p, *q`; the value of `q-p` would depend entirely upon the bit patterns held in `p` and `q`, and be completely agnostic to whether those bit patterns were still associated with valid pointers.

Comment: @supercat For the purpose of compile-time evaluation the compiler vendor must make a determination whether or not `q-p` is considered undefined behavior if they hold invalid pointer values because that affects whether or not the expression is a constant expression and thereby whether or not the program is well-formed. If would be inconsistent to _not_ consider this UB for that purpose, because subtraction of pointers pointing to objects not element of one array _is_ UB and therefore must disqualify constant expressions. But yes, I should have included pointer arithmetic at runtime.

Comment: @user17732522: The C++ Standard uses the term "Undefined Behavior" as a catch-all to encompass things that implementations are required to deterministically recognize as erroneous, things which implementations should attempt to recognize as erroneous when possible, and actions which many implementations should process in useful and predictable fashion, but for which it might be impractical for some obscure or specialized implementations to offer any kind of behavioral guarantees.  I think the rules about disqualifying expressions are limited to actions which are classified as UB...

Comment: ...by certain specific parts of the Standard, rather than all constructs which would be thus classified.  For example, if memory serves, `#include` directives with certain characters in the filenames are treated as UB by the Standard, but some file systems might require that names contain those characters in path separators.  A program that includes such characters in a `#include` directive would be non-portable, but the use of such characters in an include directive shouldn't affect template expansion.

Answer (score 16):

Pointers to objects can be used in limited ways in constant expressions, even if those objects have never lived in a constant expression, or have already died:

```cpp
// In your example, x does exist at compile time, but its lifetime ends after foo() exits.
// You cannot dereference a pointer &x after x is dead, but you can do some other things:
int x = 5;

// The address of a local variable is never null.
// GCC and clang compile this.
// You can even perform this comparison outside foo(), like in your assertion, when
// x has died.
static_assert(&x != nullptr);

// The distance between two addresses can be computed, if those addresses are
// constant expresssions. GCC and clang compile this.
static_assert(&x - &x == 0);
```

In th expression `foo() == 0`, `0` is actually a [null pointer constant](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#def:constant,null_pointer), so what you're doing is equivalent to `&x == nullptr`, although indirectly. The result of this comparison has implementation-defined effect, because `x` is dead, and `foo()` yields an *[invalid pointer value](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:value,invalid_pointer)*:

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become [invalid pointer values](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:value,invalid_pointer).
> Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.
> **Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.**

- [[basic.stdc.general] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.general#4)

The assertion:

```cpp
static_assert(foo() == 0);
```

fails for clang, and it fails for GCC since GCC 14. However, GCC 13 and below treat this invalid pointer value as equal to null, so your comparison succeeds. See [live example at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PvxEcMs1h).

Comment: The assertion passes with c++20 flag enabled. I have tried it in https://www.onlinegdb.com/MpT62yT8t

Comment: @Artyer you're right, I've updated the question. It's not a bug if this behavior was intentional, and it has changed in GCC 14, so maybe it wasn't. I couldn't find a bug report for this one, so I'm not sure why the behavior changed between versions.

Comment: @Boris I'm not sure what version of GCC is used by onlinegdb. It's better to use Compiler Explorer for these things, because it lets you compare compilers and version of the same compiler. In any case, GCC 14 and clang fail this assertion, GCC 13 lets it pass.

Comment: used --version on their site and it reports g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURP

Comment: @Artyer: GCC makes asm that returns `0` / `nullptr` for the address of a local in a non-constexpr function that isn't inlined.  https://godbolt.org/z/3b9GcT97b  This is true for GCC13.2 and GCC14-trunk, even with optimization disabled.  So I wasn't very surprised that GCC treated `foo() == nullptr` as true in a constexpr context if no rules required other behaviour.  (Using uninitialized variables also often results in zeroing a register with GCC, with optimization enabled otherwise it of course read stack space, so GCC's internals presumably tend to treat garbage values as 0)

Comment: For a small amount of added context: I'd submitted the change as a patch even before the bug report was opened for GCC only as an improvement for diagnostics when using the dangling pointer in a constant expression. The fact that it causes GCC to also start failing this assertion was just a side effect of this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110619,
which appears in GCC 13, but is fixed already in GCC trunk, where `static_assert(foo() != 0)` is true (dangling pointer is not equal to `nullptr`). Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5bbP16h5o

Please note that small modification of your program:

```
constexpr auto foo() {
    int x = 5;
    auto p = &x;    
    return p;
}

static_assert(foo() != 0);
```

(see `p` local variable introduced and returned) makes GCC 13 happy with it as well: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wx1dMzT3K

Comment: As other answers point out, this was *not* a bug in the first place (implementation-defined behaviour not undefined), but the GCC bug report and the CVS commit (https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;h=b8266af71c19a0bd7db4d08c8d2ee3c33214508c) made in response to it do explain the change.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it was not implementation-defined comparison behavior of invalid pointers in GCC, because two similar functions (original one and with `p`) both return dangling pointer, but in the first it was equal to `nullptr` ,and in the other it does not. As was explained in referenced GCC issue, `when typeck discovers that a return statement will refer to a local variable it rewrites to return a null pointer` (and it was not always consistent in the discovery). So this *rewriting* can be considered as a bug that was fixed in trunk.

Comment: Oh, I see, `invalid_ptr != nullptr` should always be true or always be false, not depending on copying through a local var in the function that returned it. (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zcs4bYE3b shows both functions at once.)  Precisely because it's implementation-defined, not undefined.  So any given implementation should pick one consistent behaviour.  I'm not sure that's strictly required, like whether the standard's wording could allow some invalid pointers to compare equal to nullptr and some not to.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what's happening is how `constexpr` functions work in C++. In your code, you're returning the address of a local variable `x` from a `constexpr` function, which is generally not a valid use case.

In C++, `constexpr` functions are evaluated at compile time when their arguments are compile-time constants in addition `constexpr` functions can also be called at runtime with non-constant arguments. In such cases, the function is evaluated at runtime, just like any regular function.

In our case `foo()` is declared as a `constexpr` function, which means "it can be evaluated at compile time if the input is a compile-time constant". However, in your code, `x` is a local variable initialized with `5`, and its address is not a compile-time constant.

You return the address of `x` as `(&x)` from `foo()`. This is already a warning sign because returning the address of a local variable from a function is a bit problematic *(It's a good practice in general to avoid returning the address of a local variable from a function because the variable's lifetime typically ends when the function exits.)*.

Then you use `static_assert` to compare the result of `foo()` with `0`. In this case, `foo()` is evaluated at **runtime**, and **it returns the address of the local variable x, which has gone out of scope**.

Why it appears to work then? Well, it's called an "*undefined behavior*" as some compilers might allow such code and set the address of the local variable to `0` as a way to indicate that the variable is no longer accessible or has been optimized away. **This behavior is not standardized**, and relying on it **can lead to unpredictable results on different compilers or compiler versions**.

Generally it's not advisable to relay on it.

Hope that helps and explains a bit.